# Adding shortcut to All Users start menu

Tags: vbscript, shortcut, shortcut-file

I have a problem with creating a shortcut in the All Users start menu (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`).

```
Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\My app.LNK")

lnk.targetpath = "C:\Program Files\my app\my  app.exe"
lnk.workingdirectory = "C:\Program Files\my app" 
lnk.save
```

Comment: So, what exactly *is* the problem? Do you get an error? A shortcut that isn't working? Nothing at all?

Comment: If I understand, need admin rights, for creating shortcut in following dir

Comment: Because, if I set another dir, scritp working

Comment: Yes. You should be getting an error if you run the script without admin permissions, though.

Comment: ...Unable to save shortcut

Comment: code: 80070005
source WshShortcut.save

Comment: The error code means "permission denied". So, run the script with admin privileges. Problem solved.

Comment: yes, that I under stand, bt how to write that in script

Comment: soory, I beginer in scripting
And sister google doesnņt help me :(

Comment: You mean you want to re-run the script with elevated privileges? Who or what will be running the script?

Comment: it's part of winrar sfx module (installation pakage)

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Will the user running this have admin privileges?

Comment: does not matter, is or no admin privileges, BECAUSE THIS IS INSTALLATION

Answer (score 1):

I found solutions for that, here is script what need add, before shortcut creat script

```
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") = False Then
  'Launch the script again as administrator
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
Else
  'Change the working directory from the system32 folder back to the script's folder.
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  oShell.CurrentDirectory = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
End If
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the user running the script is a member of the administrators group or knows the credentials of an admin account. If UAC is disabled it will fail when the user is not a member of the administrators group.

Comment: You are right, it's work only admin group user, maybe you know how to make for all users?

Comment: Not possible without embedding the credentials of an admin account. Which is not advisable.